# Why doesn't the Catholic Church view Plymouth Brethren baptisms as valid?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, brethren

The Catholic Church seems to [accept most mainline Protestant baptism as valid](https://www.dosp.org/wp-content/uploads/9_3.-Valid-and-Invalid-Baptisms.pdf), but does not recognise the baptisms of non-Trinitarian denominations. There are a few Protestant (and Trinitarian) denominations also in the invalid list however, one of which is the Plymouth Brethren. This is surprising to me.

Are there some theological problems in the Plymouth Brethren's beliefs, either about the Trinity or in the baptism formula they use, that cause their baptisms to be considered invalid in the eyes of the Catholic Church?

Comment: It’s worth noting that most RCIA programs (at least im willing to bet this was the case, it was for me) take the question of valid baptisms on a case by case basis. So it may be stated as “invalid” on the document, but it would likely be reviewed by the individual RCIA head and maybe priest.

Answer (score 4):

After looking into the Plymouth Brethren’s beliefs, it is uncertain.

The baptismal mode is proper, see [Plymouth Brethren Lesson 4](https://plymouthbrethren.org/article/4951#:%7E:text=The%20believer%20symbolically%20passes%20through,he%20is%20one%20with%20Christ.):

> 2. Formula. The formula or pronouncement at baptism is “in the name of the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit” (Matthew 28:19 NASB). The words “in the name of Jesus” or “in the name of the Lord” (or variant forms) are used in Acts 2:38; 8:16; 10:48. They seem to be an abbreviated reference, especially to distinguish it from John’s baptism (Acts 19:3-5).

Nor do they deny the Trinity, as quoted from this [article](https://plymouthbrethren.org/article/6851):

> The word “trinity” is not found in the Holy Scriptures, but it is used to describe a precious truth unfolded in both the Old and the New Testaments. The word itself means threefold or three in one.

> The doctrine of the Holy Trinity shows that the Father, Son, and the Holy Spirit, in essence, are one God. It has been asserted that, “There is one God without division in the unity of Persons, and there are three Persons without confusion in the unity of essence.”

Since the only two conditions for valid baptism are valid matter and form, I am unsure what prevents their baptisms from being considered valid.

Interestingly, [this list](https://resources.catholicaoc.org/offices/tribunal/valid-baptisms#:%7E:text=When%20the%20correct%20form%20and,sacraments%20exists%20until%20proven%20otherwise.) from the Archdiocese of Cincinnati does not include the Plymouth Brethren under valid or invalid baptisms.

Comment: I was doing research on their beliefs and came across those 2 resources as well.  There is [a more official source](https://www.plymouthbrethrenchristianchurch.org/beliefs/) but couldn't find references to baptism formula and Trinitarian formula there (yet).  Both [*Encyclopedia Britannica*](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Plymouth-Brethren) and [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_Brethren) only say about their concept of clergy as distinctive; they would have mentioned Trinity / baptism if they deviate from mainstream.

Comment: Another resource worth looking is *brethrenarchive.org* which hosts an apologetics by a Plymouth Brethren adherent [Henry A. Ironside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_A._Ironside) (1876-1951) against Baptist attack from [Dr. Augustus H. Strong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus_Hopkins_Strong) (1836-1921): [The Teaching of the So-called Plymouth Brethren: Is it Scriptural?](https://www.brethrenarchive.org/archive/later-exclusivism/grant-section/defences/the-teaching-of-the-so-called-plymouth-brethren-is-it-scriptural/).

Comment: There's also the intention to perform the baptism that Christ instituted.

Answer (score -1):

**Why doesn’t the Catholic Church view Plymouth Brethren baptisms as valid?**

In the mind of the Catholic Church, Plymouth Brethren are considered an ecclesiastical community and not a Christian Church. More in question is the fact that they practice rebaptism which is an invalid baptism, seeing that normally first baptism would be considered valid in the eyes of the Catholic Church. Plymouth Brethren seem to count other baptisms of other denominations as invalid!

In order for baptisms to be recognized as valid by the Catholic Church all the conditions for baptisms must be completely and properly fulfilled including the fact that baptisms must be administered with the intention of the Church.

A valid baptism depends for its sacramental validity upon several components which are necessary for any valid sacrament: **proper minister, matter, form, subject, and intention.** The necessary intention for a valid baptism is, simply, "generally to do what the Church does." This is not to intend what the Church intends, but to do what the Church does, i.e., simply baptize. This general intention suffices, even if the minister and the subject hold to a heretical doctrine of the sacrament being conferred. So long as one intends seriously to perform the rite of baptism, that is, seriously to perform the Christian rite however understood, the intention is valid for the administration of the sacrament. So long as one merely intends to do what Our Lord Jesus Christ or the true Church do in baptism (even in opposition to the Catholic Church's doctrine), such a baptism is valid, even if heretical views are maintained on the baptism itself. Heretical views on the sacrament of order do not invalidate baptism. This position is precisely the position Saint Augustine of Hippo took against the Donatist schism, and it has been the general and authoritative teaching of the Church since the fourth century. Saint Thomas Aquinas echoes this teaching in the *Summa Theologica*, Supplement, Question 38, Second Article. Cardinal Robert Bellarmine defends this very point in his *On the Sacraments In General* I.21. Those who dissent from the Catholic Church can validly baptise, even if they hold doctrines on the very sacraments themselves that are at odds with the Church, as long as the Church's basic rule on baptism is preserved.

The problem with their baptisms is that they cannot baptize someone as with the intention of the Catholic Church, especially as they allow total freedom of belief and no creed or confession. This poses a serious question about what the Plymouth Brethren believe in regards to the **Sacrament of Baptism**!

> Plymouth Brethren, a Christian denomination, called by themselves simply Brethren, and sometimes called also Darbyites after one of their leaders. **They have no written creed or confession, and every one is allowed entire freedom of belief**; yet they hold the total depravity of man, the necessity of regeneration by the Holy Spirit, and the atonement by the sufferings and death of Christ. They believe that Christianity is in ruins, as appears in the sectarian divisions; and that believers should withdraw from the churches, and meet in separation from all ecclesiastical evil. They reject any special designation or ordination to the office of the ministry, regarding all. true Christians as priests, who, if they are found able to edify the brethren, are authorized to preach and administer the sacraments without any human call or ordination. **As a body they practise adult baptism only; they do not make it a condition of membership, yet generally convince their members of the importance of being rebaptized.** They partake of the Lord's supper every Sunday morning, and believers only are expected to meet then. In the afternoon or evening they preach to such as are not yet converted; but they consider pleading out of place in the assembly of believers. - [Plymouth Brethren](https://chestofbooks.com/reference/American-Cyclopaedia-10/Plymouth-Brethren.html)

As the Catholic Church normally recognizes most baptisms, the idea of rebaptizing adults is forbidden unless the first baptism is proven invalid. This is however the norm of the Plymouth Brethren, yet ***”convince their members of the importance of being rebaptized.”*** This type of baptism is without a doubt invalid.

Comment: If the bolded parts are the *only* reasons why the Catholic church reject their baptism, this apply to Baptists too, who separate membership from adult baptism.  They also rebaptize people who have been baptized as infants.  I don't think your answer provide sufficient reasoning for the Catholic church to reject their baptism.

Comment: And I’m curious how this interacts with Wikipedias statement: “The view of the Catholic Church is that Protestant denominations cannot be considered churches but rather that they are ecclesial communities or specific faith-believing communities because their ordinances and doctrines are not historically the same as the Catholic sacraments and dogmas, and the Protestant communities have no sacramental ministerial priesthood”

Comment: @LukeHill Good point, which is yet another reason why this answer is insufficient.  *All* Protestant churches, including those whose baptisms the Catholic Church deems "valid" are ecclesiastical communities.  By now I can see the logic behind it, but shouldn't factor into the logic of deeming whether a baptism is valid, since the logic for valid baptism seems solely on *how* the baptism is performed and understood, apart from the ecclesial stance (i.e. whether the priesthood is understood as sacramental, apostolic succession, etc.) Remember how a Catholic lay *CAN* perform valid baptism too!

Comment: "They have no written creed or confession, and every one is allowed entire freedom of belief" This is not an accurate description of the Brethren movement, at least from my experience (I grew up in one Brethren church.) The Brethren are properly called a movement rather than a denomination, as each individual congregation is independent. There are no higher church hierarchical structures to enforce theological uniformity, but that doesn't mean that each congregation cannot practice church discipline.

Comment: What this means is that an individual Brethren church could become misled into heresy, but on the whole that seems uncommon (excluding the Exclusive Brethren), and as far as I know almost all Brethren churches would still be strongly Nicene. There's not too much difference between a Brethren church and an independent Baptist church, the main thing being their different leadership models. To be consistent the Catholic Church should consider any independent church like this in the same way. That may mean interviewing the person to identify the teachings of the church, to check they're Nicene.

Comment: (Also: like other Protestants, Brethren do believe in the priesthood of all believers, but they also have a very strong form of eldership/presbyters (and often deacons too.) They don't have three offices, like many other Protestants, believing presbyters and episkopoi are synonymous. Being elder led many, but not all, Brethren churches do not have "ministers". But they make up for it with a strong eldership. It's better than the Presbyterian system, which I call the "Animal Farm" system - all Presbyterian elders are equal, but some are more equal than others!)

Comment: "Those who dissent from the Catholic Church can validly baptise, even if they hold doctrines on the very sacraments themselves that are at odds with the Church"  In light of this, how does re-baptizing adults invalidate anything?  According to your own answer, what they believe about the sacrament of Baptism doesn't matter at all.  "This general intention suffices, even if the minister and the subject hold to a heretical doctrine of the sacrament being conferred.".  I don't understand this answer at all.

Comment: Further, on the note of “no creed” I don’t think the Catholic Church denies baptismal validity to “no creed but Christ” churches. This answer definitely overlooks some key counter examples